# Warning when battery is fully charged

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

I would like to get an alert (with sound) when my laptop battery is fully charged.

How can I do that?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: hi, windows 7 home edition. hp notebook dv6 6190.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Laptop Battery Monitor](http://download.cnet.com/Laptop-Battery-Monitor/3000-2094_4-10442542.html):

> Laptop Battery Monitor, is an intelligent laptop battery monitoring
>   software. It accurately displays an estimated time, until your battery
>   will discharge, or fully charge. You no longer have to worry on how
>   much battery power you have left, when you can have this information
>   in hours, minutes and seconds. Features are display remaining time
>   until the battery is fully discharged (when running on batteries),
>   display remaining time until the battery is fully charged (when the
>   battery is charging from the AC power supply), application runs in
>   system tray, using minimum memory, and screen space, custom indicator
>   colors, **sound alerts when charging starts/stops, battery is full
>   charged, or battery charge drops under a predefined percentage,
>   automatically starts when you turn on your laptop.** Works with any
>   laptop and battery model, new or used.

Comment: The Laptop Battery Monitor is not available on CNET for download anymore. While searching for similar app I found opensource project @ http://batteryalarm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

The following script alerts you when the battery has charged to 96%, and when it falls to 5%. You can edit the line if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox “Battery is at ” & iPercent & “%”,vbInformation, “Battery monitor” and replace the value in (iPercent > 95) to whatever value suits you. Save the script below as Battery.vbs in your Startup folder to have it run automatically.

```
set oLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
set oServices = oLocator.ConnectServer(".","root\wmi")
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batteryfullchargedcapacity")
for each oResult in oResults
iFull = oResult.FullChargedCapacity
next

while (1)
set oResults = oServices.ExecQuery("select * from batterystatus")
for each oResult in oResults
iRemaining = oResult.RemainingCapacity
bCharging = oResult.Charging
next
iPercent = ((iRemaining / iFull) * 100) mod 100
if bCharging and (iPercent > 95) Then msgbox "Battery is at " & iPercent & "%",vbInformation, "Battery monitor"
wscript.sleep 30000 ' 5 minutes
wend
```

From [this link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/get-alerts-when-your-laptop-battery-is-low-or-full/)