# Alarm when battery is fully charged on laptop - Third party app

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, alarm

I would like to get an alert (with sound) when my laptop battery is fully charged.
I checked many softwares on the net and none of them has that capability.
Also there is a depricated thread on SuperUser and that software's link does not exist anymore.

[Warning when battery is fully charged](https://superuser.com/questions/428818/warning-when-battery-is-fully-charged)

---

My laptop can not support win 11 & win 10 and i stuck on win 7. It is not important. There was an app before that can raise a sound during 3 situations :

1. Fully Charged Alarm
2. Charge Less Than ??%
3. Connect To Power Supply

I am searching for that app ---> I found a link about it.
But that app has been infected.

Comment: The link you gave has an answer containing a VBS script that can do the job.

Comment: It seems it has bug and there no escape from loop. I prefer to use an app instead of script. Also the copy paster user is new and not trustable. Some years ago after run such this loop my laptop went to Blue Screen Of Death. So the owner of this script is enjoying loops all the time. By the way in these days people do n't use VB as programming language anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install from the Microsoft Store the
[Battery Notification app](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/battery-notification/9WZDNCRD31FK) :

> With Battery Notification, you don't have to worry again about leaving your device while the laptop/tablet is being charged. The Charge Notification will play Notification sound to notify you when your battery is fully charging.

[image]

Comment: My laptop can not support win 11 & win 10 and i stuck on win 7. It is not important. There was an app before that can raise a sound during 3 situations : 1-Fully Charged Alarm 2-Charge Less Than ??% 3-Connect To Power Supply ---> I am searching for that app ---> I found a link about it ---> But that app has been infected.